# I created a login form in flutter to connect in Mysql. But if I fill the username textfield. The password will also simultaneously fill?

Tags: mysql, flutter, dart, authentication

I created a login form in flutter to connect in Mysql. But if I fill the username textfield with data. The password textfield will also simultaneously fill with the same data I inputted on username textfield? How do I solve it? This is the codes.

1. login.php codes

   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fmDWa.jpg)
2. login_screen.dart codes

   https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1y-BD1j59zX76gyYpS5rQhNn8DvjSTNQ5?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

It is because you have the same controller in both `TextField`

Just change The **controller** in the second `TextField`

**For userName**

```
TextField(
     controller: username,
),
```

**For Password**

```
TextField(
         controller: password,
    ),
```

Comment: thank you so much. <3

Comment: You can mark this answer as the right one if it helped you. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

dont use same controller for TextField, create another controller for password TextField